# Doing the opposite of pivot in pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to do the opposite of pivot in pandas. Wondering whether someone can provide some assistance? Trying to transform the data from the below

```
|Date|A|B|C|D|E |
|----|-|-|-|-|--|
|2005|1|2|3|4|50|
|2006|6|7|8|9|10|
```

to

```
|Date|X|Val|
|----|-|---|
|2005|A|1  |
|2005|B|2  |
|2005|C|3  |
etc 
|2006|A|6  |
etc
|2006|E|10 |
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index(name='Val').rename(columns={'level_1':'X'})
print (df)
   Date  X  Val
0  2005  A    1
1  2005  B    2
2  2005  C    3
3  2005  D    4
4  2005  E   50
5  2006  A    6
6  2006  B    7
7  2006  C    8
8  2006  D    9
9  2006  E   10
```

Or [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), but there is different ordering of values:

```
df = df.melt('Date', var_name='X', value_name='Val')
print (df)
   Date  X  Val
0  2005  A    1
1  2006  A    6
2  2005  B    2
3  2006  B    7
4  2005  C    3
5  2006  C    8
6  2005  D    4
7  2006  D    9
8  2005  E   50
9  2006  E   10
```

So for same output add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (df.melt('Date', var_name='X', value_name='Val')
        .sort_values(['Date','X'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   Date  X  Val
0  2005  A    1
1  2005  B    2
2  2005  C    3
3  2005  D    4
4  2005  E   50
5  2006  A    6
6  2006  B    7
7  2006  C    8
8  2006  D    9
9  2006  E   10
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Cheers

Comment: I made this by the second solution 'melt'. Thanks!