# I want to pivot down the data from column level to row level in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have data in the below format

| Head | Sub Head | Sub Sub Heads | 20210401 | 20210501 | 20210601 | 20210701 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales Accounts | Indirect Tax | GST Return Filing | 11000 | 7000 | 8500 | 3500 |

[Source Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma85t.png)

However, I want to transform it to the below format using Python

[Target Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HimjH.png)

Comment: [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doing the opposite of pivot in pandas Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135994/doing-the-opposite-of-pivot-in-pandas-python)