# Transpose a table using python

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I have this table that I need to transpose it in a very specific way using Python:

[image]

But I need to transpose it this following way:

[image]

Meaning to transpose the headers except for the first column and then the first row with the first value on the first column, then repeat for all stores.

Comment: use this link to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135994/doing-the-opposite-of-pivot-in-pandas-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doing the opposite of pivot in pandas Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135994/doing-the-opposite-of-pivot-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = (
    df.set_index("Store")
    .stack()
    .rename("Sales")
    .rename_axis(["Store", "Qrt"])
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Store       Qrt  Sales
0   Store 1  FQ2 2022   0.51
1   Store 1  FQ4 2022   0.53
2   Store 1  FQ2 2023   0.70
3   Store 1  FQ4 2023   0.74
4   Store 2  FQ2 2022   0.65
5   Store 2  FQ4 2022   0.65
6   Store 2  FQ2 2023   0.33
7   Store 2  FQ4 2023   0.34
8   Store 3  FQ2 2022   0.56
9   Store 3  FQ4 2022   0.76
10  Store 3  FQ2 2023   0.67
11  Store 3  FQ4 2023   0.33
12  Store 4  FQ2 2022   0.58
13  Store 4  FQ4 2022   0.77
14  Store 4  FQ2 2023   0.67
15  Store 4  FQ4 2023   0.30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.set_index('Store').stack().reset_index(name='Sales').rename(columns={'level_1':'Qrt'})
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise alternative to the answers already given is

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars="Store", var_name="Qrt", value_name="Sales")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html